# variable for pdf file is referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Ive tried running my code and this error message comes up, please help. This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tauau/OneDrive/Desktop/IS104/Assignment/Assign1_S11151996_2.py", line 34, in \<module\>
generate_invoice(client_name, project_name, estimated_hours, hourly_rate)
File "C:/Users/tauau/OneDrive/Desktop/IS104/Assignment/Assign1_S11151996_2.py", line 13, in generate_invoice
pdf_file = pdf_file.pdf()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pdf_file' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you please post your code at least? but based on the error message of `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pdf_file' referenced before assignment` its means that you tried to call the variable of `pdf_file` before it has been assigned a value within the current scope of the function. To fix this, you need to assigned a value first to the `pdf_file` variable before you wanted to use it

Comment: We can't possibly help without seeing the full code, which you did not post.

Comment: Also please dont post images of code, if you were planning on that. Refer [help] on creating good, answerable posts.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see that your error says "variable 'pdf_file' referenced before assignment".

This means that you tried to use the `pdf_file` before you told python what `pdf_file` is.
The error message also tells you exactly where the error occurred.
`Assign1_S11151996_2.py, line 13, in generate_invoice`.

`pdf_file = pdf_file.pdf()`

My best guess is that you're trying to convert some file into a pdf and then store it inside `pdf_file`. If so, you probably want to do this

```
pdf_file = {insert the correct file variable}.pdf()
```